# How to build C# object from a FormCollection with complex keys

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

i have a javascript object, `obj`, that gets passed to an mvc action via a $.post() like so:

```
var obj = {
    Items: [{ Text: "", Value: { Property1: "", Property2: "" },
            { Text: "", Value: { Property1: "", Property2: "" }]
};
$.post('MyAction', obj, function() {});
```

the action signature looks like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection collection)
{
}
```

i need to be able to build an object from the `FormCollection`, however i'm running into an issue where the keys are in the form:

```
"Items[0][Text]"
"Items[0][Value][Property1]"
"Items[0][Value][Property2]"
"Items[1][Text]"
"Items[1][Value][Property1]"
"Items[1][Value][Property2]"
```

i'm wondering if there's a clean way to build the desired C# object from the given `FormCollection`.  i understand that i could change the action method signature to take in the type of object i'm interested in, but that was presenting its own issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the javascript side so you're sending in a json version of the data instead, I would think you could either accept a string and do a json deserialization yourself in the controller or do a model binder to do it for you.

- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/
- [ASP.Net MVC : Sending JSON to Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140845/asp-net-mvc-sending-json-to-controller)
- http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: thanks.  as you suggested, i ended up sending a json string to the action and writing a custom model binder using json.net for deserializing the request.